# Wordpress AJAX doesn't work - response 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want add AJAX support to my plugin and I have huge problem with this simple thing. WordPress isn't permitting me to use normal AJAX and I need to use WordPress version.

At all times, the WordPress function (that should generate output) returns 0. And I think that the reason is that WP doesn't trigger 'function'. I try to force the function to run many times, but I don't have any idea what I can improve.

```
<?php
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

$options = get_option('Free_Quotation_options');
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {        
        var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            action: 'fqtag',
            data: {
                'whatever': 'text'
            },
            success: function (output) {
                $('#secondary').append(output);
            }       
        });
    });

</script> 
<?php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_fqtag', 'fqtag' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_fqtag', 'fqtag' );

function fqtag() {
    global $wpdb; 

    echo 'echo';

    die(); 
}
}
```

I try to add alert('echo'); to the test function, but it doesn't have any effect. I think that AJAX doesn't run the proper function: fq_tag_support_callback() .

On the beginning I had a problem with ajaxurl variable. It was not defined. It's not a normal situation. I attempt to resolve this problem by using:

```
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
```

Do you have any idea, how can I try to solve this problem?

---EDIT--- After discussion with David I have file like this (all time doesn't work)

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: TEST PLUGIN
    Description: TEST
    Author: Krzysztof Kubiak
    Version: 1.0
*/
function Test_01_settings_init(){
    register_setting( 'Test_01_settings_filed', 'Test_01_options', 'Test_01_validate' );
}
add_action('admin_init', 'Test_01_settings_init' );

function T01_init_method() {         
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');      
}   
add_action('init', 'T01_init_method');

function Test_01_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( 'Test_01', 'Test_01', 'manage_options', 'T01_menu_page', 'T01_add_page' );
    echo my_test();
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'Test_01_menu_page');

function my_test(){
    echo 'Function test';
}
function T01_add_page() {
    echo 'TEST_01_plugin';
}

function Test_01_validate($input) {
}   

//AJAX FROM HIRE

function test_callback() {
    $whatever = 8;
    echo $whatever;
    die();
}       
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_fqtag', 'test_callback', 1 );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_fqtag', 'test_callback', 1 );

function print_js() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        action: 'fqtag',
        data: {
            'whatever': 'text'
        },
        success: function (output) {
          alert(output);
        }       
    });
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_print_footer_scripts', 'print_js', 1000);
?>
```

Comment: If you look at the source for the page is the jquery.js file being included? It should be, but if not you'll need to enqueue it. Do you see your JS in the source as well?

Comment: Yes:
Remote Address:[::1]:80
Request URL:http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0 

For example when I add this line in jQuery(documet) script:
$( "#secondary" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
It works perfect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove

```
<script>alert('echo');</script>
```

your response should be echo if you check your console. I suspect all the above code is in your plugin functions file. Basically the php function should be placed in the functions file.

The jquery should be placed in the template from which you want to receive the response.

Place this in your functions file...remove the jquery from the class...

```
add_action('wp_print_footer_scripts', 'print_js', 1000);

    function print_js() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'action': 'test_callback',
                'whatever': 'text'
            },
            success: function (output) {
              alert(output);
            }       
        }); 

    });
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Move this outside your class...

```
 function test_callback() {
                    $whatever = 8;
                    echo $whatever;
                    die();
 }

 add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_testaction', 'test_callback' );
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_testaction', 'test_callback' );
```

Comment: Hi.
I add this part of code only for test it. Without this part I have the same result - 0 in console...
This parte of code is in main plugin file like I write to @WisdmLabs .

Comment: updated something else to try, its essentially the same code but i know it works...

Comment: It's really sad to say, that the result is 0 . (you miss one coma before success ;) ).

I think that problem is not exactly in AJAX, but in PHP part of code. This part of code doesn't work and the result is JS output 0.

Comment: i dont think its that, intval returns 0 for text but you are not outputting that. But try commenting it out anyway. It still seems like the function is not found. What is the page url you have the jquery code on?

Comment: I edit my code in question (to be accordance with your suggestion). The output of this code is also... 0.
Page URL: http://localhost/wordpress/
I use this server many times before to try AJAX function in non WordPress work.

Comment: well i cant look at that! can you paste the template code into pastebin and ill have a look at it?

Comment: Sorry that I was "silent" but I was on delegation out of my computer. I put my files hire: http://pastebin.com/fzB4iryX
 
It's complete test plugin with ajax functionality that doesn't work. I think, that I do some error, because my problem is not connected with one plugin, but now I create new simple test plugin and I get the same problems...

Comment: I can't edit tamplate - this plugin is available in WordPress repository. All files should be in plugin file.

Comment: You can keep it in your plugin file, just move it outside the class in the plugin file. What i think is happening, is that the function that outputs this code is being called too late to attach the functions to the ajax handler - the function testcallback() dosent exist until its outer function is called, whereas adding a function in your plugin file exists immediately. The add action in this case calls the function when the ajax hook is called.

Comment: It doesn't solve a problem... 
I think that everything that you talk   is logical and I think that the problem is in this situation - ajax doesn't see the function ant in result can't start it (function is undefined).

Comment: well thats a seperate issue (i assume your console says undefined?).... basically if jQuery is undefined, you are adding it in before jQuery is available, most themes will now load at the footer stage whilst your widgets are called before that. Ill update a function and hook for you to try.

Comment: Updated it above. If you are still getting undefined errors, check the page by view source and see if jquery is loaded, if not that will have to be loaded..

Comment: Hi, I update my question with whole code (it's easy to look on it, copy and create simple plugin on your side to test it on your WP test environment).

It also doesn't work after your last suggestion. In console I doesn't have any errors. I have properly loaded jQuery. And I really doesn't have any idea now, why it doesn't work.

Comment: sorry had a syntax error in the jquery ajax, updated it there and confirmed working with 20/14 theme.

Comment: You made one small mistake: data 'action': should be 'testaction'.

And now it work! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that you have put the function 'fq_tag_support_callback()' in your plugin's main file.

Comment: Yes - this function is in main file of my plugin. I had problem with option some times ago, and now I always try to move code to main plugin file to check reason of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

I see few problems here. Action should inside the **data object**, not as a jQuery Ajax parameter. Also in the callback function data is stored in $_POST variable.

```
function test_callback() {

    $whatever = $_POST['whatever'];
    echo $whatever;

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fqtag', 'test_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_fqtag', 'test_callback');

function print_js() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: <?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'fqtag',
                whatever: 'text'
            },
            success: function (output) {
                alert(output);
           }       
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_print_footer_scripts', 'print_js', 1000);
?>
```